# How to add type hints to scikit-learn functions?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, mypy, python-typing

I have the following simple function:

```
def f1(y_true, y_pred):
    return {"f1": 100 * sklearn.metrics.f1_score(y_true, y_pred)}
```

According to the scikit-learn documentation, the arguments to `f1_score` can have the following types:

- `y_true`: 1d array-like, or label indicator array / sparse matrix
- `y_pred`: 1d array-like, or label indicator array / sparse matrix

and the output is of type:

- float or array of float, shape = [n_unique_labels]

How do I add type hints to this function so that mypy doesn't complain?

I tried variations of the following:

```
Array1D = NewType('Array1D', Union[np.ndarray, List[np.float64]])

def f1(y_true: Union[List[float], Array1D], y_pred: Union[List[float], Array1D]) -> Dict[str, Union[List[float], Array1D]]:
    return {"f1": 100 * sklearn.metrics.f1_score(y_true, y_pred)}
```

but that gave errors.

Comment: Your usage of `NewType` is incorrect - the second argument must be a single class. You probably just want a type alias `Array1D =  Union[np.ndarray, List[np.float64]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the approach I use to avoid similar mypy issues. It takes advantage of [numpy typing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/typing.html) introduced in 1.20. The `ArrayLike` type covers `List[float]`, so no need to worry about covering it explicitly.

Running mypy v0.971 with numpy v1.23.1 on this shows no issues.

```py
from typing import List, Dict
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt
import sklearn.metrics


def f1(y_true: npt.ArrayLike, y_pred: npt.ArrayLike) -> Dict[str, npt.ArrayLike]:
    return {"f1": 100 * sklearn.metrics.f1_score(y_true, y_pred)}

y_true_list: List[float] = [1, 0, 1, 0]
y_pred_list: List[float] = [1, 0, 1, 1]
y_true_np: npt.ArrayLike = np.array(y_true_list)
y_pred_np: npt.ArrayLike = np.array(y_pred_list)

assert f1(y_true_list, y_pred_list) == f1(y_true_np, y_pred_np)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Array1D = NewType("Array1D", Union[np.ndarray, List[np.float64]])
```

you may use

```
Array1D = Union[np.ndarray, List[np.float64]]
```